# Problems while attempting to load file from inside a jar

Tags: java, resources

I've been looking around for some solutions for this problem, but it doesn't seem like any have helped.

I'm trying to load a file ("soundfile.wav") so I can then use it in my playSound method. I want it to load from a jarfile when I export it, so you don't see the file when downloading.

```
package soundplayer;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;

public class SoundPlayer extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String code = "up up down down left right left right b a";
    static SoundPlayer soundPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
        soundPlayer.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SoundPlayer()
    {
        //Look and feel
        String lookAndFeel = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
        try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException| IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e2) {e2.printStackTrace();}

        //Window Stuff
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(50, 50, 250, 80);
        setTitle("Sound Player Test");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        //Components
        final JTextField typingArea = new JTextField(1);
        typingArea.setText("up up down down left right left right b a");
        typingArea.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
        getContentPane().add(typingArea);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Now playing: ");
        label.setBounds(10, 40, 400, 25);
        label.setVisible(false);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JButton button = new JButton("Check");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if(typingArea.getText().equals(code))
                {
                    setBounds(50, 50, 250, 110);
                    label.setVisible(true);
                    File file = new File("sound.wav");
                    playSound(file);
                }
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(125, 10, 100, 25);
        getContentPane().add(button);
    }

    public static void playSound(File file)
    {
        try
        {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
            clip.start();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line

```
File file = new File("sound.wav");
```

This is directly accessing the Filesystem. What you want instead is to load a resource from your JAR.
This can be accomplished using the Classloader:

```
getClass().getResource("sound.wav");
```

You will then have a resource which provides the getInputStream as well, so you don't pass a File to the playSound, but the resource.